# Custom Button with Onclick , Hide Onclick Event

Tags: delphi, events, components

I've created a Custom Button . I hook it up with a Grid . And I've made custom code for the On-click event .

The Code bellow is simplified for easier understanding .

Everything works, if I click the Button the Message is shown . But since I am running a lot more code here . I would like to hide if possible all events for this button . Is that possible even if I am actually using TcxButton as my Parent Class ?

```
unit cxGridButton;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.StdCtrls, cxButtons,
  cxGridDBTableView, Dialogs;

type
  TcxGridButton = class(TcxButton)
  private
    FGridView : TcxGridDBTableView;

  protected
    { Protected declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
     procedure Click; override;
  published
    property DBGridView : TcxGridDBTableView read FGridView write FGridView;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure TcxGridButton.Click;
begin
  inherited; // call the inherited Click method.

  ShowMessage('AHA');
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('James', [TcxGridButton]);
end;

end.
```

Comment: This is a very common and standard thing. Once a property is published, it's there for good. As Remy answers, you can specifically target those properties which you don't want to show in the IDE. But you can't keep users from writing code which interacts with them. You'd have to dig deep and roll out your own button control for that.

Comment: that 'AHA' is funny though :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At *design-time*, you can hide a `published` property from the Object Inspector by calling [`UnlistPublishedProperty()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/DesignIntf.UnlistPublishedProperty) when you register your component.

At *run-time*, you can't prevent code from being able to access `public`/`published` properties.